# What does it mean when a device has the option set to nodev in the /etc/fstab file?

Tags: linux

I know that nodev means `Do not set character or special devices access on this partition.` but what does that exactly refer to. My understanding of character devices is a device that reads and writes in stream such as the console or terminal and a block device is one that reads and write in fixed block sizes such as CDs, DVDs and disk sectors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Device nodes are special files that allow interaction with physical devices (usually) such as hard disks and video cameras etc.

They normally exist in /dev which is commonly part of the root file system.

The nodev parameter on a partition is saying "even if someone manages to create a device node on this partition, we will not treat it as a device".

So you would use this to tighten the security of other file systems, such as `/home`, so someone can't create a `/home/user/dev/sda1` and have it actually represent a physical device.

Comment: Thanks Paul. That makes sense however how would one create a device node?

Comment: That is a different question :)  The command is `mknod`